# ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 tabulate area outputs blanks or zeroes in zone field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, area, tabulate

I am tabulating the area of HUC10 polygons (a little over 4,000 of them) using LandFire raster biophysical classes, but everything I have tried outputs a zone field that is either blank or full of zeroes.  For the zone field, I have tried using the "tnmid" column of HUC10 (a long alphanumeric string), I have tried using a shorted version of that (using the first 10 characters) and I have copied the FID column to a new numeric column.

The alphanumeric options all result in a blank zone field (huc10_ID):
[image]

And the numeric option results in a zone field column of zeroes (huc10_row):
[image]

They are currently in the same CRS, WGS 84 (although I did run it when they were not - NAD 83 and WGS 84).  There are the same number of rows as there are zones.  The calculations look okay.  I just need the zone field to print.  Any ideas of what I've done wrong or how I can work around whatever the issue is?

Comment: Use projected system; use fid for zones field - column; set extent to zones; specify cell size.

Comment: Thanks Felix!  Unfortunately, I got the same results using FID as the zone field - a column of zeroes.  I don't have a place where I can "set extent" in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7, but cell size is defined by the raster being calculated for area (the path to the .tif file is in the optional processing cell size field).  Any other thoughts?

Comment: To set extent go to environment settings,  also worth to run repair geometry and converting your polygons to raster.

Comment: Thank you for your help and specific instructions.  Unfortunately, I have tried every combination of setting the extent, repairing geometry and converting the polygons to a raster (including all three), but the problem persists.  I get a zone field of zeroes.

Comment: This is very strange, I use this tool often. Perhaps select few large polygons and repeat with small cell size, output to in_memory\abc

Comment: Agreed!  I broke down and used QGIS' zonal histogram to accomplish the same task, but I'm still perplexed too.  I'll try smaller subsets - that's a great idea - just to see if I can get ArcGIS to cooperate.  Thank you so much for your help!